# libtldl not found - chekc libtool installation!

Tags: make

I'm on Fedora 8, trying to configure/make libmp3splt, and every time I try to compile I get

```
libtldl not found - chekc libtool installation!
```

I have libtool installed, and some places online said to try installing libltdl-dev, which does't seem to exist for me to install. Missing anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was libtool-libtldl-devel